# javascript array with element ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loaded an array in javascript with a select amount of input element ids on the form.  Some of the input elements are radio buttons & checkboxes,.

What I would like to do is something jQuery where I'm looping through my array and passing in the id like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= myArray.length - 1;i++){
alert($(myArray[i].val());
}
```

I'm getting an error when I do this.  Is there a way to do what I want?

**UPDATE:**

My array contains the IDs of the elements.  My elements have numeric values as their IDs.
For example in my array #50:0 and #51:0 are elements of the array.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="50:0" type="radio" value="1" name="50:0">Yes
<input id="50:0" type="radio" value="2" name="50:0">No

<input id="51:0" type="checkbox" value="1" name="51:0">Option 1
<input id="51:0" type="checkbox" value="2" name="51:0" >Option 2
<input id="51:0" type="checkbox" value="3" name="51:0" >Option 3
```

Assume that you clicked Yes and Options 1 & 3  I need those values...

Comment: Actually, IDs are not allowed to start with a digit (just FYI): http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: @Felix - It's worth noting at this point that the rules change with HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#the-id-attribute As long as there are no spaces and it's unique, it works.

Comment: hmmm...  That is news to me.  I will certainly change that up to start with a letter.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Craver: Thanks, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off, it should be this:

```
for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  alert($(myArray[i]).val());
}
```

The `$(selector)` was missing it's closing `)`.  Also make sure your elements in the array are prefixed with a `#`, otherwise you'll need `$('#' + myArray[i])` instead, to make it an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

And a readability tip, you can replace `i <= myArray.length - 1` with just `i < myArray.length`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up...  When I try to alert out the val() I get an undefined...  Specifically the element is a type of checkbox.  I've also tried to do a radio button and got the same results.

Comment: @Jeff - Are you using ASP.Net? Prior to 4.0, they don't have a value client-side, look at your markup and check for the `value=""` attribute.

Comment: I'm able to hack with regular javascript and get the values for each element.  I'm really hoping there is something cleaner by using jQuery...  I am using VS2010 but I'm really displaying everything via jQuery and JSON.  All the elements are dynamic (I'm writing the HTML on the fly).

Comment: @Jeff - Are you running this in a `document.ready` handler, so the elements are there before it loops?  If not the selectors probably aren't finding any elements :)

Comment: @Nick yeah I am doing the document.ready and the same issue is occurring...  What is need to get is the selected (or checked) value(s)...  I updated the original question too.

Comment: @Jeff - IDs have to be unique, so remove those and use the names instead, like this: `$('input[name="' + myArray[i] + '"]:checked').val()`

Comment: @Nick - I will try that.  So it sounds like I should re-write the way I am displaying my elements.  Should I just use the name attribute?

Comment: @Jeff - Yup, radio buttons are meant to be grouped by name, just removing IDs is *probably* what you're after in this case

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing parenthesis.

```
alert($(myArray[i]).val());
```

And make sure that you strings are `#foo` and not just `foo`.